# Concatenate Columns if Other Fields Match

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab delimited file with 6 fields.  If fields `$1`, `$2`, `$4`, `$5`, and `$6` match, I want to merge them into a single row and concatenate field `$3` with a `/` between each value.

**input.txt**

```
1   109860777   COSN18724706    CT  C   SORT1
1   154842199   COSM3685920 G   GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3
1   154842199   COSM5827506 G   GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3
1   1684347 COSM1320773 C   CCCT    NADK
1   1684347 COSM1320774 C   CCCT    NADK
1   1684347 COSM5827581 C   CCCT    NADK
1   248801602   COSM246232  T   TCA OR2T35
```

**output.txt**

```
1   109860777   COSN18724706    CT  C   SORT1
1   154842199   COSM3685920/COSM5827506 G   GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3
1   1684347 COSM1320773/COSM1320774/COSM5827581 C   CCCT    NADK
1   248801602   COSM246232  T   TCA OR2T35
```

I've tried using awk, but I could use a push in the right direction.

Comment: So when you said $1, $2, $4, $5, and $6 match, you meant fields all the records. So $3 is uniq through ut the record right ?

Comment: $3 is uniq, that is correct.  I was able to work through the problem already with guidance from the other answers.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ k=$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;  a[k]=(k in a)? a[k]"/"$3 : $3 }
     END{ for(i in a) { 
              split(i,b,FS); b[3]=a[i]"\t"b[3]; r=""; 
              for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) { 
                  r=(r!="")? r"\t"b[j] : b[j] 
              } 
              print r 
        } 
     }' input
```

The output:

```
1   1684347 COSM1320773/COSM1320774/COSM5827581 C   CCCT    NADK    
1   109860777   COSN18724706    CT  C   SORT1   
1   154842199   COSM3685920/COSM5827506 G   GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3   
1   248801602   COSM246232  T   TCA OR2T35
```

---

*Details*:

- `k=$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6` - complex array key
- `a[k]=(k in a)? a[k]"/"$3 : $3` - concatenating the 3rd field value for records with matched/grouped fields
- `split(i,b,FS)` - split array key by separator
- `b[3]=a[i]"\t"b[3]` - inserting the resulting (3rd field) value into respective position

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed` for ease of code appearance we can do it as follows:

```
sed -Ee '
   $!N
   s|^(\S+\t\S+\t)(\S+)(\t\S+\t\S+\t\S+)(\n)\1(\S+)\3$|\4\1\2/\5\3|
   /^\n/!P;D
' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
1       109860777       COSN18724706    CT      C       SORT1
1       154842199       COSM3685920/COSM5827506 G       GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3
1       1684347 COSM1320773/COSM1320774/COSM5827581     C       CCCT    NADK
1       248801602       COSM246232      T       TCA     OR2T35
```

---

### Working

- Invoke `GNU sed` with the `-E` option to enable the extended REs.
- Load the next line in the pattern, unless it is the eof.
- We have assumed that there were no leading/trailing TABs and no multiple TABs as well between fields.
- Club $1 $2 into \1, $3 into \2, $4,$5,$6 into \3.
- Then try to make the sub as shown. If successful, then we we would have moved the $3 of the next line into the $3 of the current, separated by a slash AND a newline at the BOL.
- Then we print the current line on failure of the sub, OTW, we redo the sed code with what we have in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that using Python:

#### Code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict()
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.split('\t')
        key = tuple(line[:2] + line[3:])
        data.setdefault(key, []).append(line[2])

with open('file2', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in data.items():
        f.write('\t'.join([k[0], k[1], '/'.join(v)] + list(k[2:])))
```

#### Results:

```
1   109860777   COSN18724706    CT  C   SORT1
1   154842199   COSM3685920/COSM5827506 G   GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT,GGCTGCTGCTGCTGCTGCT    KCNN3
1   1684347 COSM1320773/COSM1320774/COSM5827581 C   CCCT    NADK
1   248801602   COSM246232  T   TCA OR2T35
```